# React-Redux: Add quantity value to a table in order/cart

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to create a purchase order screen and I am facing issues while adding the quantity of the product.

Workflow
a)Fetch the product details from state and get in the drop down. Select the product from drop down
b)Add the quantity in the text field. Click on Add
c)This will add the product details to a table.

But I am not sure how to set a constant quantity for each product selected.

[image: Screen for reference]

Now when I am not sure how to add the quantity to the product selected.
Sorry, the code might be messed up, I am still learning. Adding the code below.

```
let count=0;
    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [medicineName, setMedicineName] = useState('')
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0)
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])

    const productList = useSelector( state => state.productList )
    const { loading, error, products } = productList
    
    const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)
    const {userInfo} = userLogin

    const [dropDownData, setDropDownData] = useState(products)

    useEffect(()=>{
           setDropDownData(products)
        },[products])

    useEffect(() => {

        if(!userInfo){
            history.push('/login')
        }
        
        dispatch(listProducts())

    },[dispatch, history, userInfo])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const arr = dropDownData.filter((product) => 
            product.medicineName.toLowerCase().indexOf(medicineName.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        
        setTableData(tableData => tableData.concat(arr))
        const arr2 = dropDownData.filter((product) => 
            product.medicineName.toLowerCase().indexOf(medicineName.toLowerCase()))
        
        setDropDownData(arr2)
        
    }

return(
        <>
        <h2>PurchaseOrderScreen</h2>
        
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler} validated={validated} noValidate>
        <Row>
            <Col md={7}>
                <Form.Group controlId='medicineName'>
                    <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingSelect" label="Medicine">
                        <Form.Control as='select' value={medicineName} className="mb-3"
                                onChange={(e) => setMedicineName(e.target.value)}
                                required
                                >
                                <option value=''>Select Medicine</option>
                                {dropDownData.map(product => (
                                    <option value={product.medicineName}>{product.medicineName}</option>
                                ))  }
                            </Form.Control>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                        
                </Form.Group>
            </Col>
            <Col md={3}>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId='quantity'>
                    <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingInput" label="Quantity" >
                        <Form.Control   type="text"  placeholder="Quantity"
                                        value={quantity}
                                        onChange = {(e)=> setQuantity(e.target.value)}
                                        required 
                                    />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
            </Col>
            <Col md={2}>
                <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
                    >Add
                </Button>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        </Form>

        <Table striped bordered hover responsive='md' className='table-sm mt-3' id="table-to-xls">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><span className='btn'>Remove</span></th>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>Sl</span></th>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>Medicine</span></th>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>C.stock</span></th>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>Quantity</span></th>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>Low Stock</span></th>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>Reorder Quantity</span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {tableData.map(product => (
                                    <tr key={product._id} >
                                        <td> X </td>
                                        <td>{count+1}</td>
                                        <td>{product.medicineName}</td>
                                        <td>{product.currentStock}</td>
                                        <td>{quantity}</td>
                                        <td>{product.lowStockValue}</td>
                                        <td>{product.reOrderValue}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )) }
                        </tbody>                        
                </Table>
```

Can you please let me know how the quantity can be added. Please let me know if you need any details.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the filtering is for in the `submitHandler` but there is where you want to access the form's field values from the `onSubmit` object and map the current `tableData` array into a new array and update the matching row's quantity property.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response... The filter is because - I get the data from the product state which has multiple products..so I use filter to get the product selected from the dropdown.. this process happens in the submit handler when the add button is clicked

Comment: Oh, I see now, and that's why you concat it back into the `tableData` state. This looks like it would append a lot of duplicate rows if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah it would create duplicates. I dint know how to stop it. So i removed the product from dropdown after it was added to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add the quantity to the table, you need to store it somewhere.  You have an array called `tableData` that you currently are adding your products to.  Maybe instead of adding the products, you could add an object:

```
// Inside the submitHandler function
const productToAdd = dropDownData.find((product) =>
   product.medicineName.toLowerCase().indexOf(medicineName.toLowerCase()) > -1);
const rowToAdd = {product: productToAdd, quantity: quantity};
setTableData(tableData => [...tableData, rowToAdd])
```

and then later in your render:

```
{tableData.map(row => (
  <tr key={row.product._id} >
    <td> X </td>
    <td>{count+1}</td>
    <td>{row.product.medicineName}</td>
    <td>{row.product.currentStock}</td>
    <td>{row.quantity}</td>
    <td>{row.product.lowStockValue}</td>
    <td>{row.product.reOrderValue}</td>
  </tr>
)) }
```

Comment: fwiw, I would also definitely consider several other changes to this code - but this should answer your actual question.

Comment: `setTableData(tableData => tableData.push(rowToAdd))` will update the `tableData` state to the new length of the `tableData` array after the push, just FYI.

Comment: @idbentley I tired it and it works. Awesome!! Thanks for the help. I tried setTableData(tableData => tableData.push(rowToAdd)) as per Drew but it throws error . I guess it because .push returns the length of array rather than the array it self. Thanks both of you

Comment: @kiran - Drew was correcting an error in my original solution.  I adjusted my solution before you used it.  You are correct about why it doesn't work.

Comment: @idbentley Oh.. got it... thank you again!